Custom Specfiles with SDK
We are having an issue with the SDK. Specifically we can't do transfers. We have clients using our solution via VPN using either SymXchange or jxchange. Other OLB vendor's SDK have some methodology for performing basic share to share transfers. However, we are trying to do everything with the SDK connection to simplify implementations. I know that there is no SDK calls to perform SymXchange calls but can it be done directly by calling a specfile on the core? Is there really no way to perform basic transfers? That seems like a giant hole in the functionality of the SDK.
We can't perform transfers or so any major custom dev work with the SDK>

The Banno Digital Toolkit doesn't support making calls to the core, as that's the domain of jXchange/SymXchange.
